# When Installing a Plugin Where do I Move Template Files to?

Tags: plugins

I just installed a WP plugin cron-view

I can't find where it is or what it's actually done.  When going to the install directions though - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cron-view/installation/

I get:
"Upload your post template files (see the Description for details on configuring these), and choose them through the new menu."

But that assumes that you know where (relative to the root directory) this is supposed to be put.

Thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After activation, the plugin is available under the Tools menu > What's in Cron?

The text telling you to upload template files is from another one of his plugins, [custom post template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/installation/), looks like a little copy / paste error there. Cron View has no template files to move.